# UISplitViewController disable interactivePopGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, interactivepopgesture

My app is laid out in a storyboard like this

[image]

The problem is I cannot disable the popGestureRecognizer for the "Book Player View Controller" (see bottom of image)

This happened after I introduced the splitview setup. Is there a different way to disable this gesture if you're using a SplitViewController?

I'm using iOS 8 as the base sdk.